# For loop with if-else statement to unzip files

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Compared to other solutions (eg. using the "find" tool), I would like to get a solution that uses the common:

```
for z in *zip
do
   unzip $z
done
```

however, my parent zip file often has 2, 3, 4 or 5 levels of zipped files. So, for a 2-levels parent zip file I can do:

```
for z in *zip
do
   unzip $z
   for x in *zip
   do
      unzip $x
   done
done
```

which is a pretty basic (or archaic) solution. I was wondering if an if-else call could be included inside it (e.g., `[[ -a *zip ]]`) to automagically get all zip files without looping again on the ones that have been already unzipped. The tricky part is that the parent zip file must remain in the current directory (I could use `cd` or `mkdir` to move it but it may exist a cleaner way).

Any hints are much welcomed,

Comment: is zip structure flat (ie. all contents are in current directory, no subdirectories or absolute paths)? Are unpacked zips guaranteed not to overwrite an existing zip?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/extracting-nested-zip-files) discussion.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for the link, I am looking for something like this: `while set -- *.zip; [ $# -ge 1 ]; do for z;do ( cd -- "$(dirname "$z")" && z=${z##*/} && unzip -- "$z" && rm -- "$z"); done; done` the only issue is to remove all "child" zip files but keeping the parent zip file. I tried to change the position of the `rm` call but no success so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow to extract the files in hierarchy structure according to
the zip files, would you please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# return nonexistent dirname such as "name(1)"
#
newname() {
    local name=$1                       # dirname which already exists
    local new                           # new dirname
    local i=1                           # number for the suffix
    while :; do
        new=$(printf "%s(%d)" "$name" "$i")
        [[ ! -e $new ]] && break        # break if the newname is unique
        (( i++ ))                       # increment for the next loop
    done
    echo "$new"                         # return the new name
}

#
# extract zip files in the directory which name is the basename of the zip file
#
extract() {
    local zip                           # zip filename
    for zip in "$@"; do
        if [[ -f $zip ]]; then          # check the existence of the file
            local dir=${zip%.zip}       # generate the dirname removing extension
            if [[ -e $dir ]]; then      # if the dirname collides
                dir=$(newname "$dir")   # then give a new name
            fi
            unzip "$zip" -d "$dir"

            extract "$dir"/*.zip        # do it recursively
        fi
    done
}

extract *.zip
```

For instance, if you have following files:

- level1.zip contains file1, file2, file3 and level2.zip.
- level2.zip contains file4 and file5.

then the extracted result will have a structure like:

```
.
|-- level1
|   |-- file1
|   |-- file2
|   |-- file3
|   |-- level2
|   |   |-- file4
|   |   +-- file5
|   +-- level2.zip
+-- level1.zip
```

**[Explanations]**

- The `extract` function unzippes the zip files recursively creating
  new directories with the basename of the zip files.
- The `newname` function is used to avoid filename collisions if
  the directory name to create already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you think `find` is not a `for` loop, while it loops over directories faster.

### task

```bash
tree
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c
│   │   │   ├── d
│   │   │   │   └── hello.zip
│   │   │   └── hello.zip
│   │   └── hello.zip
│   └── hello.zip
└── hello.zip

4 directories, 5 files
```

### find them

```bash
mapfile -t zips < <(find -name \*.zip)
```

### unzip them

```bash
for zip in "${zips[@]}"; do unzip "$zip" -d "${zip%/*}"; done
```

### done

```bash
tree
.
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c
│   │   │   ├── d
│   │   │   │   ├── hello.txt
│   │   │   │   └── hello.zip
│   │   │   ├── hello.txt
│   │   │   └── hello.zip
│   │   ├── hello.txt
│   │   └── hello.zip
│   ├── hello.txt
│   └── hello.zip
├── hello.txt
└── hello.zip

4 directories, 10 files
```

[image]